# Unable to set Target Server Version to SQL Server 2012 for Integration Services Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I'm trying to create a new Integration Services project. By default the project targets SQL Server 2017. I need it to be SQL Server 2012, but the option is not showing up. I have existing projects which have been set to 2012 a while back, but now I can't do it anymore.

[image]

Any clue on why the SQL Server 2012 option isn't showing up? Is it a compatibility issue?

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 v15.9.7 with SSDT v15.1.61901.24070.

Comment: Latest version of SSDT is 15.9, maybe updating will resolve? SQL Server 2012 support was temporarily removed in 15.8 but should be in 15.1

Comment: Thanks @TomNash, I thought I had the latest version for some reason. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I was mistaken, you may have the most up to date. Check the build number in `Add/Remove Programs`, should be 14.0.16186.0

Comment: I had 14.0.16182.0, which is version 15.8.2. It's odd, when I go to Help > About in Visual Studio it shows 15.1.61901.24070. I'm updating now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest version of SSDT is 15.9, maybe updating will resolve? SQL Server 2012 support was temporarily removed in 15.8 though.

Answer (score 4):

That is the version of Visual Studio that you are using. To get the correct version of SSDT, you need to go into About or into Add/Remove Programs and get it for SSDT.

Anyways, the problem is that Microsoft removed Targeting to SQL Server 2012 in SSDT version 15.8.1 and subsequently re-added it in SSDT version 15.9.0 (i.e., the latest as of this posting).

Just upgrade SSDT and you will have it.

**Note:** Uninstall SSRS and SSAS if they are installed otherwise the SSDT upgrade will fail and you will have lots of heartburn getting it installed again.

[change log is for SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/changelog-for-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)